# Algorithm to find number of premuations using bounds?

Tags: algorithm

I'm wondering if there's an algorithm to tell me how many results I'd get if I am looking for permutations within bounds.

I have a program that looks for combinations. The best way to explain is it vai an example, say you have 4 items you want to buy at a store: apple,peach,pear and orange. You want to know how much percent you can fit of each into a basket but you tell yourself you want a min. of 20 of each item and a max of 60 of each item(so apple:25, peach:25, pear:25, and orange:25 works perfectly but not apple:0, peach:0, pear:50, and orange:50 because we set a min of 25).  If you ran this example, the correct number of items returned would be 1771.

Is there a way to calculate this in advance instead of running the actual program?  I have a program that needs to do premuations and I'm trying to find the ideal mix, so I wanted to write a program that gives me the correct output then I'll do a monte carlo simluation on the inputs to find the mixture of items/ranges I like.

Here's the program I used(it works in my case when the top band is never used, but if the ranges are tigher, 1-4 then it doesn't work because it gives me the combinations without considering the ranges):

```
import math

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print nCr(20+4-1,20)  #percent+buckets(items)-1, percent
```

this gives me the correct answer(1771) because it doesn't need to factor in the max(60) because its never reached(it only uses 20 as the input). But is there a way I could modify this formula(or use something else) that would tell me how many results to expect if I have something like 40 items with a range of 2-5 or something(something that factors in the max value as well).

Is there an algorithm that can do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Is the capacity of the basket in your initial example 100 items?  In the program you wrote, it sounds like you are saying that your basket has capacity 20 and you are choosing among 4 item types, which is the same as saying that each item has at least count 20 and your basket has capacity 100.

Comment: I think you should stop using percentages in your examples, because in reality you want these operations only on the positive integers. Just say you want 100 items, 25 of them apples etc...anyway +1, I would love to see a closed formula for this.

Comment: @MartinHock yes the capacity is 100, but in the first example, if the min is 20 for 4 items then its 100 - 4 * 20 = 20 remaining to be found.

Comment: @chris Thanks, I removed the percentages, I just did it because I thought it was make my example of what I'm doing make more sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number with the inclusion-exclusion principle. Let `distributions(itemCount,bucketCount)` be the number of unrestricted distributions of `itemCount` items to `bucketCount` buckets. I disregard the lower limit because that's dealt with simply by subtracting `bucketCount*lowerLimit` items.

The number of ways to distribute `itemCount` items to `bucketCount` buckets with each bucket containing at most `upperLimit` items is the number of unrestricted distributions minus the number of unrestricted distributions where at least one bucket contains more than `upperLimit` items. The latter can be calculated with the inclusion exclusion principle as follows:

- There are `bucketCount` choices of a bucket to contain at least `upperLimit+1` items, there remain `itemCount - (upperLimit+1)` items to distribute to `bucketCount` buckets:

  ```
  bucketCount * distributions(itemCount - (upperLimit+1), bucketCount)
  ```

  must be subtracted from the number of unrestricted distributions.
- But we have subtracted the distributions where two buckets contain more than `upperLimit` items twice, we must correct that and add

  ```
  nCr(bucketCount,2) * distributions(itemCount - 2*(upperLimit+1), bucketCount)
  ```

  again, because there are `nCr(bucketCount,2)` choices of the two buckets.
- But we have subtracted the distributions where three buckets contain more than `upperLimit` items thrice, and added it again thrice (`nCr(3,2)`), so we have to subtract

  ```
  nCr(bucketCount,3) * distributions(itemCount - 3*(upperLimit+1), bucketCount)
  ```

  to rectify that. etc.

All in all, the number is

```
 m
 ∑ (-1)^k * nCr(bucketCount,k) * distributions(itemCount - k*(upperLimit+1), bucketCount)
k=0
```

where

```
m = min { bucketCount, floor(itemCount/(upperLimit+1)) }
```

(since there is no way to distribute a negative number of items).

Corrected code from your gist with an implementation of the function to count the ways of distributing the items respecting lower and upper limits:

```
import math

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

def itemCount_cal(target, items, minValue):
    return target- items*minValue

def distributions(itemCount, bucketCount):
    # There's one way to distribute 0 items to any number of buckets: all get 0 items
    if itemCount == 0:
        return 1
    # we can't distribute fewer than 0 items, and we need at least one bucket
    if itemCount < 0 or bucketCount < 1:
        return 0
    # If there's only one bucket, there's only one way
    if bucketCount == 1:
        return 1
    #get all possible solutions
    # The number of ways to distribute n items to b buckets is
    # nCr(n+b-1,n)
    f = math.factorial
    return f(itemCount + bucketCount-1)/(f(itemCount) *  f(bucketCount-1))

def ways(items,buckets,lower,upper):
    if upper < lower: # upper limit smaller than lower: impossible
        return 0
    if buckets*upper < items: # too many items: impossible
        return 0
    necessary = buckets*lower
    if items == necessary:  # just enough items to meet the minimum requirement
        return 1
    if items < necessary:   # too few items: impossible
        return 0
    # put the minimum required number in each bucket, leaving
    # items - necessary
    # to distribute
    left = items - necessary
    # We have put 'lower' items in each bucket, so each bucket can now take
    # at most (upper - lower) more
    # any more, and the bucket is overfull
    over = upper + 1 - lower
    # maximal number of buckets we can put more than upper in at all
    # after we fulfilled the minimum requirement
    m = left // over
    # We start with the number of ways to distribute the items disregarding
    # the upper limit
    ws = distributions(left,buckets)
    # Sign for inclusion-exclusion, (-1)**k
    sign = -1
    # Number of overfull buckets
    k = 1
    while k <= m:
        # Add or subtract the number of ways to distribute
        # 'left' items to 'buckets' buckets with
        # k buckets overfull
        #
        # nCr(buckets,k) choices of the buckets we overfill at the start
        #
        # That leaves (left - k*over) items to distribute.
        ws += sign * nCr(buckets,k) * distributions(left - k*over,buckets)
        # flip sign and increment number of overfull buckets
        sign = -sign
        k += 1
    return ws
```

Note that for large numbers of items and buckets, calculating `nCr` with the factorial is not the best way, it leads to large intermediate results and uses more operations than necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the n00b question, I'm trying to understand what your doing.  Isn't item count and bucket count the same? I thought both were the # of items or is bucketcount the #items and itemcount the range(in the above example 40(20-60)?  Also, Chris is right I will be test this against anywhere from 5 to 100 items with various ranges to understand the distribution.

Comment: `itemCount` corresponds to the percentage. So in your example, you have four buckets, and `100- 4*20 = 20` items (since you have the lower limit of 20).

Comment: Thanks David. I'm not very good at math and tried to follow what you said(not sure I fully understood it) but I'm not getting the correct result. I did make a modification because I was getting errors with negative numbers I flipped the order of itemCount in the formula because item count(4) is always lower than upper limit(60). I don't know what to do because if I keep in the current order than I get a python error saying it cannot use negatives. If you can take a quick peek here's the code: https://gist.github.com/9493d7f6f1f47561ea0c

Comment: I've added code, modified from your gist, with comments hopefully explaining things more. By the way, it's _Daniel_, not 'David'.

Comment: opps I'm so sorry, I didn't mean to get your name wrong. Just a bit out of it I guess. Thanks Daniel, I'll study your example and try to figure it out..sorry again about calling you the wrong name..

Comment: No problem, as long as you don't call me bad names, a wrong one isn't something to worry too much about.

Comment: lol. I would never call you a bad name..only thing I curse at is my computer for being more strictly logical than me.  I'm not quite sure I understand how to even run this code(your comments makes the logic make sense)..I try to run `print ways(20, 4, 20,60)` to get the example above but instead of 1771 I get 0 because it gets caught here: if `items < necessary:`

Comment: That would be `ways(100,4,20,60)`. If we removed the 80 items demanded by the minimum requirement before calling `ways`, we wouldn't need the lower limit for anything but adjusting the upper limit.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. You are beyond awesome! My analysis is going awesome..thanks Daniel!<<--I got it right this time :-)